# ESP8266 node MCU recebendo comandos em JSON

Tags: c

Bom eu estou codificando uma ESP8266 em C no qual a ESP recebe um comando através de JSON: eu tenho que pegar os dados deste JSON (uma String) e convertê-los para char* aí conseguir enviar estes dados para realizar uma conexão http ou https.
Eis o código:

```
char* str_to_char(String S) {
  char strAux[S.length() + 1];
  strcpy(strAux, &S[0]);
  return strAux;
}

void getBufferData(DynamicJsonDocument dataBuf) {
  String str;
  if (dataBuf.containsKey("address")) {
    if (dataBuf["address"].containsKey("proto")) {
      str = dataBuf["address"]["proto"].as<String>();
      proto = str_to_char(str);
      Serial.print("proto: "); Serial.println(proto); 
    }
    if (dataBuf["address"].containsKey("host"))
      host = str_to_char(dataBuf["address"]["host"].as<String>());
    if (dataBuf["address"].containsKey("path"))
      path = str_to_char(dataBuf["address"]["path"].as<String>());
    if (dataBuf["address"].containsKey("file"))
      file = str_to_char(dataBuf["address"]["file"].as<String>());
  }  
  if (dataBuf.containsKey("coordinates")) {
    if (dataBuf["coordinates"].containsKey("X"))
      crdX = dataBuf["coordinates"]["X"].as<int16_t>();
    if (dataBuf["coordinates"].containsKey("Y"))
      crdY = dataBuf["coordinates"]["Y"].as<int16_t>();
  }
  Serial.print("host: "); Serial.println(host); 
  Serial.print("path: "); Serial.println(path); 
  Serial.print("file: "); Serial.println(file); 
  delay(10000);
}
```

Só que no print do final da função ele traz um monte de besteiras, e nada parecido com uma string, parece mais binários.

Observem que na primeira instrução tento trazer tudo para variáveis mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

O teu problema principal (não procurei mais) é na função `str_to_char()`.

Estás a criar uma variável local nessa função com o nome `strAux`. Essa variável deixa de existir assim que a função termina, mas devolves o endereço dela à função chamante. Quando a função chamante tenta usar esse valor dá erro pois o objecto já não existe.

Tens várias soluções (por ordem de preferência)

1. Cria o objecto destino na função chamante e passa-o como parametro

   ```
   char *str_to_char(char *dst, String S) {
     strcpy(dst, &S[0]);
     return dst;
   }
   //...
       char proto[1000]; // tamanho suficiente
       str_to_char(proto, str);
   //...
   ```
2. Usa `malloc()` na função

   ```
   char *str_to_char(String S) {
     char *dst = malloc(strlen(S) + 1);
     if (!dst) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     strcpy(dst, S);
     return dst;
   }
   //...
       char *proto;;
       proto = str_to_char(str);
       // usar proto
       free(proto);
   //...
   ```
3. Usa `static` para que o objecto não seja destruído quando a função termina

   ```
   char *str_to_char(String S) {
     static char strAux[1000]; // static: não usar em threads ou paralelismo
     strcpy(strAux, &S[0]);
     return strAux;
   }
   // ...
       char *proto = str_to_char();
   // ...
   ```